# Explain the functionality or meaning of this : $data['row']

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller

I have this doubt.

```
// This is my controller

public function profile()
{   
  $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
  $uid= $session_data['id'];
  $pic = $this->user_model->getImage($uid);
  $data['profile_pic']= $pic ;
  $data['row'] = $this->user_model->get_user_data($uid);
  $test = $this->load->view('profile_view',$data,TRUE);
  echo $test;exit;
}
```

Comment: and what **exactly** do you not understand?

Comment: `$row` is an associative array and 'row' is one of its elements. More: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: so the value of 'row' is $uid. am i correct.

Comment: what inside in row please check `user_model` `get_user_data` function

Answer (score 0):

Based on name it seems to be:

```
public function profile()
{   
  $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');//checking user login or not
  $uid= $session_data['id'];//getting id from session
  $pic = $this->user_model->getImage($uid);//geting user image
  $data['profile_pic']= $pic ;//storing image to data array
  $data['row'] = $this->user_model->get_user_data($uid);//passing $uid to model and store in data array what row model returns
  $test = $this->load->view('profile_view',$data,TRUE);//passing data array to view
  echo $test;exit;
}
```

//model 
i am passing user id only

```
public function get_user_data($uid){

    //echo $uid;exit;

    $data = array();
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('user');
    $this->db->where('id',$uid);
    $query = $this->db->get();//checking that $uid data in database
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            $get_user_data=$query->result();
            //print_r($get_user_data);exit;
            //print_r($items);exit;
            return $get_user_data; // if find, return data to controller
            }
        else{
            return FALSE;
        }

    //return $query->row();
}
```